# dynamic xml generation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-3.0

We have incoming JSON data from Source which has data and column in same payload. Using json-to-xml in XSLT I was able to generate XML like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <boolean key="allData">true</boolean>
   <map key="factMap">
      <map key="T!T">
         <array key="rows">
            <map>
               <array key="dataCells">
                  <map>
                     <string key="label">1A</string>
                     <string key="value">1A</string>
                  </map>
                  <map>
                     <string key="label">1B</string>
                     <string key="value">1B</string>
                  </map>
                  <map>
                     <string key="label">1C</string>
                     <string key="value">1C</string>
                  </map>
               </array>
            </map>
            <map>
               <array key="dataCells">
                  <map>
                     <string key="label">2A</string>
                     <string key="value">2A</string>
                  </map>
                  <map>
                     <string key="label">2B</string>
                     <string key="value">2B</string>
                  </map>
                  <map>
                     <string key="label">2C</string>
                     <string key="value">2C</string>
                  </map>
               </array>
            </map>
            <map>
               <array key="dataCells">
                  <map>
                     <string key="label">3A</string>
                     <string key="value">3A</string>
                  </map>
                  <map>
                     <string key="label">3B</string>
                     <string key="value">3B</string>
                  </map>
                  <map>
                     <string key="label">3C</string>
                     <string key="value">3C</string>
                  </map>
               </array>
            </map>
         </array>
      </map>
   </map>
   <map key="detailColumnInfo">
      <map key="Product_vod__c.F1">
         <string key="dataType">string</string>
         <string key="label">F1</string>
      </map>
      <map key="Product_vod__c.F2">
         <string key="dataType">string</string>
         <string key="label">F2</string>
      </map>
      <map key="Product_vod__c.F3">
         <string key="dataType">string</string>
         <string key="label">F3</string>
      </map>
   </map>
</map>
```

Here each row is available under dataCells tag as label and value. Value under dataCells represents value of field however label does not represent field name. Field names and field order is part of detailColumnInfo tag. Order and number  of fields/data in is not fixed however target XML shall remain fixed. E.g. incoming data can have 10 fields and data in any order however target XML shall have only 2 fields. To implement this, I believe, on run time we have to figure out the order of F1 field and have to pick corresponding data from dataCells. E.g. if F1 is field is first field in  detailColumnInfo then I have to pick first value from all dataCells (1A, 2A, 3A)and generate target XML with value of F1 field and so on.

Detailcolumninfo tag represents the column details. Position of value field in Detailcolumninfo will determine the position of fields in Datacells. For input code snippet posted in query, if F1 is the 1st label in Detailcolumninfo then first value in Datacells (1A,2A,3A) represents the value of F1. Similarly 1B,2B,3B represents value of F2. Target XML should look like following:

```
<Root>   
<Rows> 
<Row> 
<F1> 1A </F1> 
<F2> 1B </F2> 
<F3> 1C </F3> 
</Row> 
<Row> 
<F1>2A </F1> 
<F2> 2B </F2> 
<F3> 2C </F3> 
</Row> 
<Row> 
<F1>3A </F1> 
<F2> 3B </F2> 
<F3> 3C </F3> 
</Row> 
</Rows>
```

Can anyone suggest possible solutions to implement such dynamic mapping.

Comment: I have not understood what determines the relation between the columns and the fields and the order. Is the number in e.g. `Fx` the indicator of the position? How would the XML result look for the input snippet you posted? How would it vary for a different input snippet?

Comment: I would love to help but I really haven't been able to work out the basic essentials of the problem: what is your input, what is your current output, what is your expected output, what is the code that is producing the incorrect output?

Comment: Detailcolumninfo tag represents the column details. Position of value field in Detailcolumninfo will determine the position of fields in Datacells. For input code snippet posted in query, if F1 is the 1st label in Detailcolumninfo then first value in Datacells (1A,2A,3A) represents the value of F1. Similarly 1B,2B,3B represents value of F2.
Target XML should look like following:
<Root>
<Rows>
<Row>
<F1> 1A </F1>
<F2> 1B </F1>
<F3> 1C </F3>
</Row>
<Row>
<F1>2A </F1>
<F2> 2B </F1>
<F3> 2C </F3>
</Row>
<Row>
<F1>3A </F1>
<F2> 3B </F1>
<F3> 3C </F3>
</Row>
</Rows>
</Root>

Comment: Please edit the question and provide code there as well-formatted code snippets.

Comment: Still hard to understand given mal-formed examples like `<F2> 1B </F1>`. Do you simply want to map the first `array key="dataCells"` to the first `Row`, the second to the second `Row`, but each take the element names from the `map key="detailColumnInfo"` element? Or is the `1` in `F1` also somehow an index to use to access rows?

Comment: I have edited and corrected the output. Under key = “detailColumnInfo” value of each <map> represents each field. Under  such map, label represents field name. F1  is 1st field and corresponding data of this field is 1st map under all dataCells i.e. 1A, 2A and 3A. F2  is 2nd field and corresponding data of this field is 2nd map under all dataCells i.e. 1B, 2B and 3B.
To summarize detailcolumninfo determines 2 aspects i.e.position of field and field name. Position of field is used to extract the same position values from dataCells and field name is used to create  the tag names in target XML

Comment: I think my posted answer produces the result you want.

Comment: Worked for most data but for few incoming data faced following situation:
If field value is null then incoming data is:
<map>
<string key="label">1A</string>
<string key="value">1A</string>
</map>
<map>
<string key="label">1B</string>
<null key="value"/>
</map>
<map>
<string key="label">1C</string>
<string key="value">1C</string>
</map>
</array>
</map>
Script is scrambling values like following:
<Rows>
<Row>
<F1>1A</F1>
<F2>1C</F2>
</Row>
Value of F3 gets copied in F2 and F3 tag is missed. Expected op is
<Row>
<F1>1A</F1>
<F2/>
<F3>1C</F3>
</Row>
Can u ps. suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that assumes you simply want to map each `array` element with `key="dataCells"` to a `Row` element and then output its descendants `string` with `key="value"` wrapped in the label from the detailColumnInfo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math fn"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="json-xml">
        <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
            <boolean key="allData">true</boolean>
            <map key="factMap">
                <map key="T!T">
                    <array key="rows">
                        <map>
                            <array key="dataCells">
                                <map>
                                    <string key="label">1A</string>
                                    <string key="value">1A</string>
                                </map>
                                <map>
                                    <string key="label">1B</string>
                                    <string key="value">1B</string>
                                </map>
                                <map>
                                    <string key="label">1C</string>
                                    <string key="value">1C</string>
                                </map>
                            </array>
                        </map>
                        <map>
                            <array key="dataCells">
                                <map>
                                    <string key="label">2A</string>
                                    <string key="value">2A</string>
                                </map>
                                <map>
                                    <string key="label">2B</string>
                                    <string key="value">2B</string>
                                </map>
                                <map>
                                    <string key="label">2C</string>
                                    <string key="value">2C</string>
                                </map>
                            </array>
                        </map>
                        <map>
                            <array key="dataCells">
                                <map>
                                    <string key="label">3A</string>
                                    <string key="value">3A</string>
                                </map>
                                <map>
                                    <string key="label">3B</string>
                                    <string key="value">3B</string>
                                </map>
                                <map>
                                    <string key="label">3C</string>
                                    <string key="value">3C</string>
                                </map>
                            </array>
                        </map>
                    </array>
                </map>
            </map>
            <map key="detailColumnInfo">
                <map key="Product_vod__c.F1">
                    <string key="dataType">string</string>
                    <string key="label">F1</string>
                </map>
                <map key="Product_vod__c.F2">
                    <string key="dataType">string</string>
                    <string key="label">F2</string>
                </map>
                <map key="Product_vod__c.F3">
                    <string key="dataType">string</string>
                    <string key="label">F3</string>
                </map>
            </map>
        </map>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="label-names" as="xs:string*" select="$json-xml//fn:map[@key = 'detailColumnInfo']/fn:map/fn:string[@key = 'label']/string()"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$json-xml//fn:map[@key = 'factMap']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fn:map[@key = 'factMap']">
        <Root>
            <Rows>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$json-xml//fn:array[@key = 'rows']/fn:map/fn:array"/>
            </Rows>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'rows']/fn:map/fn:array">
        <Row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fn:map/fn:string[@key = 'value']"/>    
        </Row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fn:string[@key = 'value']">
        <xsl:element name="{let $pos := position() return $label-names[$pos]}">{.}</xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is

```
<Root>
   <Rows>
      <Row>
         <F1>1A</F1>
         <F2>1B</F2>
         <F3>1C</F3>
      </Row>
      <Row>
         <F1>2A</F1>
         <F2>2B</F2>
         <F3>2C</F3>
      </Row>
      <Row>
         <F1>3A</F1>
         <F2>3B</F2>
         <F3>3C</F3>
      </Row>
   </Rows>
</Root>
```