# Dynamic conversion of JSON to XML using saxon

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

We have incoming JSON data from Source which has data and column in same payload. Using json-to-xml in XSLT I was able to generate XML like following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <boolean key="allData">true</boolean>
   <map key="factMap">
  <map key="T!T">
     <array key="rows">
        <map>
           <array key="dataCells">
              <map>
                 <string key="label">1A</string>
                 <string key="value">1A</string>
              </map>
              <map>
                 <string key="label">1B</string>
                 <null key="value"/>
              </map>
              <map>
                 <string key="label">1C</string>
                 <string key="value">1C</string>
              </map>
           </array>
        </map>
        <map>
           <array key="dataCells">
              <map>
                 <string key="label">2A</string>
                 <string key="value">2A</string>
              </map>
              <map>
                 <string key="label">2B</string>
                 <string key="value">2B</string>
              </map>
              <map>
                 <string key="label">2C</string>
                 <null key="value"/>
              </map>
           </array>
        </map>
      </map>
 <map key="detailColumnInfo">
  <map key="name.F1">
     <string key="dataType">string</string>
     <string key="label">F1</string>
  </map>
  <map key="state.F2">
     <string key="dataType">string</string>
     <string key="label">F2</string>
  </map>
  <map key="dist.F3">
     <string key="dataType">string</string>
     <string key="label">F3</string>
  </map>
  </map>
     </map>
```

We have to generate following XML output.

```
<Root>   
  <Rows> 
   <Row> 
    <F1> 1A </F1> 
    </F2> 
    <F3> 1C </F3> 
   </Row> 
  <Row> 
    <F1>2A </F1> 
    <F2> 2B </F2> 
    </F3> 
  </Row> 
           </Rows>
```

We are able to generate data after taking reference from
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173669/dynamic-xml-generation-using-xslt#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173669/dynamic-xml-generation-using-xslt#_=_)
But it not working as expected for null tags.
Can anyone suggest possible solutions to implement such dynamic mapping.

Comment: I am afraid markup like `    </F2> ` is not making any sense. Where is the start tag?

Answer (score 1):

By reference to the other question you linked, I take your question to be about the fact that the values you want to extract are sometimes represented as `<string>` elements, but also sometimes as `<null>` elements.  It appears that either way, the elements of interest are distinguished by a `key` attribute with value `'value'`, so you can base your selection criteria on that.

That is, instead of using `fn:string[@key = 'value']` in your XPath expressions, use `*[@key = 'value']` or even `node()[@key = 'value']`.  There are other alternatives, but applying either of those variations to the XSL in the answer you referenced will yield a transform that handles the input you present in the manner you seem to want (notwithstanding ill-formedness in the output presented in this question, which I am taking to be unintentional).